# Custom Layout menu item shows empty if showAsAction=never

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to **add SwitchCompat to Overflow menu** using this code below:

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_dummy_content"
       android:title=""
       android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"
       app:showAsAction="never"
       app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_switch"/>

    <!-- TODO: Delete this after bug fix-->
    <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_dummy_content_2"
       android:title="Second Title"
       app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

The layout for menu_item_switch is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/menu_item_switch_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/menu_item_dummy_tasks"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

If I do **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** or anything, the switch appears **perfectly fine** and the listeners work fine. **But** as soon as I make the **showAsAction as never**. The switch **view becomes white/empty** but the onOptionsItemSelected says the clicked item is menu_dummy_content.

[image]

I also **tried** using only **TextView** in the custom layout, and that too **comes as empty**. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the showAsAction attribute to never, then these menu item will never show as action layout.

I believe you need to add Title Text in here...

```
 <item
   android:id="@+id/menu_dummy_content"
   android:title=""
   android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"
   app:showAsAction="never"
   app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_switch"/>
```

like this...

```
android:title="First Title"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to show a SwitchCompat and not a text in the overflow.